# Как разместить модуль опроса Google?

Tags: javascript, json, google-merchant-center

https://support.google.com/merchants/answer/7106244?hl=ru&ref_topic=7105160 - вот собственно о чём речь
[image: скрин что должно быть в итоге на сайте]

**Код, который используется на сайте:**

```
<!-- НАЧАЛО кода модуля опроса -->
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js?onload=renderOptIn" async defer></script>
<script>
  window.renderOptIn = function() { 
    window.gapi.load('surveyoptin', function() {
      window.gapi.surveyoptin.render(
        {
          "merchant_id": 124293965,
          "order_id": "100500",
          "email": "XXXXXXX@yandex.ru",
          "delivery_country": "ru",
          "estimated_delivery_date": "2019-04-16",
          "opt_in_style": "BOTTOM_LEFT_DIALOG"
        }); 
     });
  }
</script>
<!-- КОНЕЦ кода модуля опроса -->

<!-- НАЧАЛО кода языка опроса -->
<script>
  window.___gcfg = {
    lang: 'en_US'
  };
</script>
<!-- КОНЕЦ кода языка опроса -->
```

Но в итоге вместо формы - ошибка - ругается на JSON-Объект (который в Render там передаётся)

```
Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    at JSON.stringify (<anonymous>)
    at Object._.mf (cb=gapi.loaded_0:86)
    at Fz (cb=gapi.loaded_0:107)
    at cb=gapi.loaded_0:107
```

при вызове этого вот [скрипта](https://apis.google.com/_/scs/apps-static/_/js/k=oz.gapi.ru.FiSyEuyFmBw.O/m=surveyoptin/rt=j/sv=1/d=1/ed=1/am=wQ/rs=AGLTcCPlvCPetLskLGm8yxcMMF4T2XbNfg/cb=gapi.loaded_0)

Кто сталкивался с этими гугл-отзывами - покажите примерчик как это реализовано у вас...
*тех.поддержка гугла ничего внятного ответить не может.*

Comment: Короче если кому интересна причина:
<!-- Yandex.Metrika counter --> -- гугл конфликтовал с яндекс-счётчиком.

Answer (score 0):

**Короче если кому интересна причина:**

```
<!-- Yandex.Metrika counter -->
```

**гугл конфликтовал с яндекс-счётчиком!**